# Who is to examine the witness who is the self-represented plaintiff or prosecutor?

Tags: common-law, trial, witnesses, pro-se

Bob is a self-represented plaintiff in a civil case (or, say, private prosecutor in a criminal case). He is also a witness. If the trial is judge-alone aka bench (not jury), he is [able](https://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/2011/0081/latest/DLM3360053.html) to conduct it himself.

At the hearing/trial, Bob (in his capacity as the plaintiff/prosecutor) says:

> Your Honour, I call myself.

— and goes to the witness box to be examined by... himself.

Now what? Does he ask himself questions and give answers? Or does he just make statements of fact?

(Any common law jurisdiction)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the judge. Both narrative and question-answer formats can be required.

Under the narrative format, the defendant gives their statement. The prosecution can then cross-examine.

Under the question-answer format, the defendant plays both the role of themself and the role of their representative. They ask questions to themselves then answer. This was used in United States v. Nivica, 887 F.2d 1110 (1st Cir. 1989).

Comment: Is ther actual law giving the Judge this flexibility, or is this a matter of judicial custom and precedent. Or perhaps there are judicial rules of procedure that cover this? In any case, what is the source of authority for this option?

Comment: This answer talks about the defendant, but the question is about a plaintiff or prosecutor.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Correct. But I accept that the answer is "It depends on the judge" unless someone proves otherwise.